# I want to Use TypeORM in Worker Threads , but not able to use it

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I am using SQL Server 2022 with Typeorm there I have DB intensive Task so i implements with worker threads to optimize it but as soon as I fire request to db using Typeorm, I get an error of

> Data Source is not initialized

I cannot open a new connection in the worker thread instance because in latest SQL Server when I create more than one connection I get an connection lost error.

I also tried to pass the Model Object through worker data object , then it gives me an error of DataClone Error.

```
import { parentPort, workerData } from 'worker_threads'
import { ETL_SCHEDULER_ACTION } from '../../Model/ELTDefinition/ETL_Scheduler_Action';
import { ETLScheduler } from '../../Model/ELTDefinition/ETL_Scheduler';

const { job } = workerData;

async function ETLJobExecution() {

    console.log(job)
    const eltSchedulerAction = new ETL_SCHEDULER_ACTION();

    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_ACTION_START_TIME = new Date();
    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_TASK_NAME = job.ETL_SCHEDULER_TASK_NAME;
    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_DEPENDENCY = job.ETL_SCHEDULER_DEPENDENCY;
    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_ID = job.ETL_SCHEDULER_ID;
    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_SEQUENCE = job.ETL_SCHEDULER_SEQUENCE;
    {
        // Execute the job.

        // Demo job execution

        console.log(`${job.ETL_SCHEDULER_TASK_NAME} is Done`);
    }

    eltSchedulerAction.ETL_SCHEDULER_ACTION_END_TIME = new Date();

    try {
        await eltSchedulerAction.save();

        // Update the ETl Scheduler status to 1 because jobs goes under Execution / we have to neglect it in next Execution.

        let updateJob = await ETLScheduler.findOne({
            where: {
                ETL_SCHEDULER_ID: job.ETL_SCHEDULER_ID
            }
        });

        updateJob.ETL_SCHEDULER_STATUS = 1;

        await updateJob.save();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }

    parentPort.postMessage({ message: "Execution Done" })
}

ETLJobExecution();
```

I want to know how to fire DB calls from TypeORM using worker threads